# react-native ссылка-переход в telegram или браузер(сайт)

Tags: react-native

Может кто подсказать, как можно сделать что-то на подобии ссылки в приложении на основе react-native?
Конкретно надо перейти в чат бота телеграмм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

конкретно для телеграмма код такой:

```
const url = 'http://t.me/[bot-address]';
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```